# How to Align JTextArea to right?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jframe, jtextarea

[Chat windows(Please see this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQueN.png)I am developing a simple chat application using java socket and jframe . All messages are left aligned .  I want to ask that how to show messages like whatsapp chat ?

Please click on

Comment: You have to show us your code please

Comment: Please be more specific! May we download whatsup chat ? :p

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Yes @Eritrean thank you so much . i got  this